# JSON.parse error when calling a Spring boot post method

Tags: json, angularjs, spring-boot

I'm testing angularjs post calls for the project I'm going to do. Right now I'm trying to get a button press to update a notification so that it doesn't go out in the notifications list (changing its status to deleted and its deletion date to current).

In principle everything works quite well, except for an error that the browser gives me.

Here is the post method of the spring boot controller.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class DemoController {
...
@PostMapping("/Usuarios/notificaciones/borrar")
    public ResponseEntity<String> borrarNotificacion(@RequestBody Idprueba id){
        System.out.println("Borrando");
        if(id == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        Optional<Notificacion> notData = notrepo.findById(id.getId());
        if(notData.isPresent()) {
            Notificacion notificacion = notData.get();
            notificacion.setFechaeliminacion(new Date());
            notificacion.setEstado(EstadosNotificacion.BORRADA);
            notrepo.save(notificacion);
            return new ResponseEntity<>("ok", HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
```

I created this class to store the @RequestBody

```
public class Idprueba {
    private Long id;
    
    public Idprueba(Long id) {
        this.id=id;
    }
    public Idprueba() {
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    
}
}
```

This is my js method that makes the call

```
$scope.borrarNotificacion = function (id){

        $http.post("/api/Usuarios/notificaciones/borrar",id).then(
            function sucessCallback(response){
                if(response.status == 200){
                    console.log(response.data);
                    actualizar(); //This method is to refresh the frontend with data from the backend.
                }
                
            },
            function errorCallback(response){
                console.log("Fallo al eliminar");
                console.log(response);
            }
        )
    }
```

And this is the section from where I call that method.

```
<li ng-repeat="notificacion in notificaciones">Descripcion: {{notificacion.descripcion}}, Estado: {{notificacion.estado}}, Fecha envio: {{notificacion.fechaenv}}
            <div> <button ng-click="borrarNotificacion(notificacion.id)">Borrar notificacion</button></div>
            </li>
```

The action is performed correctly, the notification is hidden and the backend data is updated correctly, but in the browser I get the following error.
[image]

I have already tried JSON.stringify({"id":id}), JSON.stringify({id:id}), {id:id}, and, on the server, with only Long id.

Comment: you are responding with `"ok"` from the backend... that is not valid json data

Comment: Yes, correct, that was it, thank you very much, I tried to return null and now I don't get any error.